# Поменял в build.gradle app id, теперь в build config ставится суффикс .test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Поменял idapp (package), но теперь в build config ставится в конец суффикс .test и возникает ошибка при билде, но если я поставлю в build.gradle в конце суффикс .test то ошибка исчезает. В настройках билда нет никаких суффиксов, но они ставятся. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему сменой типа билда с дебага на релиз

Comment: Так себе решение. Приложите лучше build.gradle к вопросу.